# Openshift 4 ping to another pod doesn't work

Tags: openshift, ping

I've two pods in OpenShift 4.  On the terminal of one pod a make a ping  to the other pod. But the error message **"Name or service not found"** is returned.
What must be done for two pods to recognize each other ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ping does not take the https:// prefix.

Answer (score 0):

`ping` / ICMP traffic within clusters is often not forwarded and could not work as expected, depending on the cluster network. So you should test with other tools such as `curl` to reach other Pods. When accessing Pods directly, you are typically also not using `https://`.

Also, typically you should not access other Pods directly but instead via a `Service`.

With the above being said, in your case the name is possibly wrong. You should be able to talk to other Pods using the following hostname:

```
<pod-ip-address>.<my-namespace>.pod.cluster-domain.example
```

So for example:

```
172-17-0-3.my-namespace.pod.cluster.local
```

When accessing a Service you would typically use the following hostnames:

```
my-svc (in the same namespace)
my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example
```

Comment: I am looking for a similar example and would like to connect using pod name, how could I check from pod terminal connecting to another pod.   Could you tell what is .example in the above

Answer (score 0):

Yes ping doesn't work in OCP pod terminal. Instead you can curl url and check output